# How to find the minimum value of $|5^{4m+3}-n^2 |$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, self-learning

How can I find the minimum value of $|5^{4m+3}-n^2 |$ for positive integers $n,m$.

Is there any short answer for this problem?

Comment: $m=1,n=280,|5^{4m+3}-n^2|=275$

Comment: The minimum is indeed $275$ but I do not see a short, mathematics-free way to prove this….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Finally I found a simple proof for all non-negative integers $n,m.$

Clearly for $m=0,n=11$ we have $|5^{4m+3}-n^2 |=4.$
Then we only need to check the four cases $|5^{4m+3}-n^2 |=0,1,2,3.$

Note that $n^2≡0,1,4,5,6,9\mod10$ and $5^{4m+3}≡5\mod10 $ for any $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}_0^+.$
Hence only possible values for the last digit of $|5^{4m+3}-n^2 |$ are $0,1,4,5.$
Therefore remains are the cases $|5^{4m+3}-n^2 |=0,1.$

Note that for any $m\in\Bbb{Z}_0^+,$
$$5^{4m}≡625\mod10000,\\
5^{4m+1}≡3125\mod10000,\\
5^{4m+2}≡5625\mod10000,\\
5^{4m+3}≡8125\mod10000.$$
Hence $5^{4m+3}$ always have the last digits as $8125.$
Suppose $n^2$ have the last three digits $125.$
Then $n$ is of the form $n=10k+5$ for some positive integer $k.$
$$100k^2+100k+25=1000l+125,\\
k(k+1)=10l+1.$$
Since LHS is always even this is a contradiction.
Hence $|5^{4m+3}-n^2 |\not=0$ for any $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}_0^+.$

Can we find $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $n^2≡8126\mod10000$ or $n^2≡8124\mod10000$?
There are no integers whose squares last two digits are $26.$
 $$n^2≡24\mod100 \iff n≡\pm 18\mod50.$$
$$n^2≡124\mod1000 \iff n≡\pm 182\mod500.$$
But note that $n^2≡8124(\mod10000)\implies n$ is even and $n^2/4≡2031\mod2500.$
There is no integer with last two digits of the square is $31.$
Hence $|5^{4m+3}-n^2 |\not= 1$ for any $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}_0^+.$

> Therefore 
>   $$\min_{n,m∈Z_0^+ }⁡|5^{4m+3}-n^2 |=4.$$

Comment: Just use mikes final expression, and for $m > 0, 5^{4m} > 1$ and $|125-k^{2}| > 4$ for all $k \neq 11$. None of this necessary.

Answer (score 1):

$$|5^{4m+3}-n^2| = |5^{4m} 125 - k^2 5^{4m}| = 5^{4m} |125-k^2|$$

The minimum is 4 when $m=0$ and $k=11$.

Comment: The question says $m,n$ have to be positive integers. But if OP meant non-negative, then this is correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right!